# utilizing JPA Named Queries

Tags: java, jpa

When I create an Entity class from a database in NetBeans, it gives me the option to create Named Queries from persistent fields. Accordingly, I see these named queries listed at the top of my Entity class.

What exactly are these queries, and how can I utilize/"call" them?

I'm aware this question is more general than is preferred on SO, so I'm happy to accept a link to a tutorial that answers these questions, but I've been unable to find one myself.

Comment: NamedQueries are great (see answer below), but you can generally get rid of most of the ones that NetBeans creates for you.

Comment: haha, as with most things NetBeans creates for you...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See

- [JPA Named Queries](http://www.objectdb.com/java/jpa/query/named)

If you have:

```
@NamedQuery(name="Country.findAll", query="SELECT c FROM Country c")
public class Country {
  ...
}
```

Use with:

```
TypedQuery<Country> query = em.createNamedQuery("Country.findAll",Country.class);
List<Country> results = query.getResultList();
```

See also:

- [Annotation Type NamedQuery](http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/api/2.0/javax/persistence/NamedQuery.html)
- [Tutorial: Build a Web Application (JSF) Using JPA](http://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/Examples/JPA/JSF_Tutorial)

Comment: Thanks. This probably warrants another question, but: Is it possible to execute a named query on one entity type from within another? Say I have an entity called `issue`, backed by one DB table, which has as a field a `List<Article>`, where `Article` is another entity backed by a different table (on the same DB). Could I build a list of articles with an issueID matching the current issue by calling `TypedQuery<Article> articleList = em.createNamedQuery("Article.findByIssueId, Article.class)` from within the `Issue` class??

Comment: You can use JPQL too. [Java Persistence Query Language](http://www.objectdb.com/java/jpa/query/parameter). e.g.  `TypedQuery<Article> query = em.createQuery("SELECT a FROM Article a WHERE a.issue.id = :id0", Article.class); List<Country> results = query.setParameter("id0", id).getResultList();`