# Expression is missing from the arithmetic expression- JPA and with named query

Tags: java, mysql, jpa

I'm getting an error when I'm trying to run a query through this code. The query is tested and works outside of the named query.But, When I'm trying to use in the named query it doesn't work.

Code:

```
  @NamedQuery(name = "User.getBasketballPos", query = "SELECT 1 + count(*) as rank FROM user u WHERE u.basketballScore > (SELECT u2.basketballScore FROM user u2 WHERE u2.username = :username) ")
```

Error:

```
Exception Description: Syntax error parsing [SELECT 1 + count(*) as rank FROM user u WHERE u.basketballScore > (SELECT u2.basketballScore FROM user u2 WHERE u2.username = :username) ].
```

[17, 17] The left expression is missing from the arithmetic expression.
[18, 18] The right expression is missing from the arithmetic expression.

I scoured the internet but none of the solutions seemed to work.
Anyone know?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16074602/utilizing-jpa-named-queries

Comment: Have you tried `SELECT 1+count(u) FROM...`? JPQL is not exactly SQL!

Comment: Thank you @NikosParaskevopoulos that helped me get on the right track!